# calling different functions with getopts using bash

Tags: bash, sh, getopts

I am trying to work out how i can have multiple functions in one script and choose the function with an argument. what seems to be the issue is that if i choose a function the optarg does'nt seem to be run with the script.
in this example I would run the script as such
~# ./script.sh -a -c wordlist.txt
that to only run the first function with the wordlist of choice
same as 
~# ./script.sh -b -c wordlist.txt

```
#!/bin/bash

one()
{
for i in $(cat $wordlist); do
  wget http://10.10.10.10/$i
}

two()
{
for i in (cat $wordlist); do
  curl http://10.10.10.10/$i
}

while getopts "abc:" option; do
 case "${option}" in
    c) wordlist=${OPTARG} ;;
    a) one;;
    b) two;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: You’re missing a couple of `done`s.

Comment: i am this was just an example not the actual script im having trouble with.

Comment: If I understand the issue correctly, and I’m not sure I do, it’s because you run `./script.sh -a -c wordlist.txt`, which causes `getopts` to call see `-a` before `-c`, which causes `one` to be called before `wordlist` is asssigned. So either run `./script.sh -c wordlist.txt -a` or make sure to call `one` (or `two`) _after_ the `while` loop.

Comment: Your `case` statement shouldn't actually do much, if any, actual work. Its job is to simply recognize and remember which options were seen. *After* the loop is the right time to perform any actions, once you have *all* the information available.

Comment: @Biffen it works if i add the -a after like you said. so thankyou!!! awesome !

Comment: also makes sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When parsing command-line arguments, don't try to act on them immediately. Simply *remember* what you have seen. *After* you have parsed all the options, you can take action based on what you have learned.

Note that `one` and `two` can be replaced by a single function parameterized by the program (`wget` or `curl`) to run; while you are at it, pass the word list as an argument as well.

```
get_it () {
    # $1 - program to run to fetch a URL
    # $2 - list of words to build URLs
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        "$1" http://10.10.10.10/"$line"
    done < "$2"
}

while getopts "abc:" option; do
 case "${option}" in
    c) wordlist=${OPTARG} ;;
    a) getter=wget;;
    b) getter=curl;;
  esac
done

get_it "$getter" "$wordlist"
```

Comment: @m4lvo, left as an exercise is to validate that the user actually provided a valid wordlist file, and the user selected either -a or -b.